# Python: Remove elements from the list which are prefix of other

Tags: python

Fastest (& python) way to get list of elements which do not contain any other elements as their prefix.

(Elements can be in any order, for the sake of clarity in explanation elements are kept kind of sequential here, so if needed sorting has to be done explicitly)

Input is

```
['AB', 'ABC', 'ABCDEF', 'ABCDEFG', 'BCD', 'DEF', 'DEFGHI', 'EF', 'GKL', 'JKLM']
```

Elements eliminated:

```
'AB' prefix of 'ABC'
'ABC' prefix of 'ABCDEF'
'ABCDEF' prefix OF 'ABCDEFG'
'DEF' prefix of 'DEFGHI'
```

Expected Output

```
['ABCDEFG', 'BCD', 'DEFGHI', 'EF', 'GKL', 'JKLM']
```

**Edited**:

Adding a bit more complexity(or clarity). The average length of the list varies from 500 - 900.

Comment: Does the order matter in the output?

Comment: Yes, the result has to be sorted.

Comment: Should your output contain `'ABCDEFG'` and `'DEFGHI'`? Do you mean that you should be removing elements which _are_ prefixes of others?

Comment: As it is not prefix of any other element, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list is sorted, every element is either a prefix of the next one, or not a prefix of any of them. Therefore, you can write:

```
ls.sort()
[ls[i] for i in range(len(ls))[:-1] if ls[i] != ls[i+1][:len(ls[i])]] + [ls[-1]]
```

This will be `n log(n)` sorting plus one pass through the list (`n`).

For your current sorted list, it is marginally quicker as well, because it is linear, timeit gives 2.11 us.

A slightly quicker implementation (but not asymptotically), and more pythonic as well, using `zip`:

```
[x for x, y in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:]) if x != y[:len(x)]] + [ls[-1]]
```

timeit gives 1.77 us

Comment: For the sample data I'm trying here, the first answer looks pretty quicker.

Comment: You are right. I did sample again on an average list length of 900. The average time taken for 1000 loops by the zip logic(700us) is much better than the first logic (740us). Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Is it `n + log(n)` then? Not `nlog(n)`.

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev They use Timsort algorithm which is n log(n). Total is n log(n) + n.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension (`ls` is the name of your input list):

```
[x for x in ls if x not in [y[:len(x)] for y in ls if y != x]]
```

I doubt it is the quickest in terms of performance, but the idea is very straightforward. You are going through the list element by element and checking if it is the prefix of any element in a list of all the rest of elements.

timeit result: 11.9 us per loop (though the scaling is more important if you are going to use it for large lists)

Comment: Not really “an easy idea and readable” unless you're *very* comfortable with list comprehensions. It could stand some explanation.

Comment: @Emmet : This was the solution I was using till now, but the average time taken per loop for my case is around 240ms. 1000 loops 700us is way much better than the 1 loop 240ms(very good performance enhancement in the critical path of the code). But I still agree with you on the easy idea and readable.

Answer (score 0):

`ls.sort()` first if your list is originally unordered.

use `startswith` :

```
In [71]: [i for i, j in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:]) if not j.startswith(i)]+[ls[-1]]
Out[71]: ['ABCDEFG', 'BCD', 'DEFGHI', 'EF', 'GKL', 'JKLM']
```

or `enumerate`:

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(ls[:-1]) if not ls[i+1].startswith(v)]+[ls[-1]]
```

Compared with @sashkello's approach:

```
In [78]: timeit [v for i, v in enumerate(ls[:-1]) if not ls[i+1].startswith(v)]+[ls[-1]] 
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.6 us per loop

In [79]: timeit [i for i, j in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:]) if not j.startswith(i)]+[ls[-1]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.5 us per loop

In [80]: timeit [x for x in ls if x not in [y[:len(x)] for y in ls if y != x]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop
```

Comment: you're only comparing neighbors.  The OP specified that the input may be unsorted.

Comment: @roippi simply `ls.sort` would suffice I think ;)

Comment: yes, but you left the timings up.  And even if you update them, sorting a pre-sorted list obviously isn't representative of real-life performance.  Your algorithmic complexity *is* O(nlogn) as opposed to sashkello's O(n**2), but any timings here on this example data are not going to be near representative of reality.

Comment: I did sample again on an average list length of 900 and the average time taken for 1000 loops by most of the solution is around 790us - 825us. They are good, but for my case the accepted answer runs at 700us.

Comment: @NEB My timing snippet is posted before his editing, sashkello's answer is good now ;)