# Python removing word if subset of other word in list

Tags: python

A simple puzzle but I cannot wrap my head around it:

In words:
I have a list of words.  If in my list, the word is a "subset" of another value in list, then remove.

```
Input:  ['car', 'car-10', 'truck-20']
Output:  ['car-10', 'truck-20']
```

We have removed 'car' because it is a subset of 'car-10'.  'car-10' is not a subset of 'car'

```
Input:  ['car', 'car-10', 'car-100']
Output:  ['car-100']
```

We have removed 'car' and 'car-10' because it is a subset of 'car-100'.

The one I am really trying to solve,  don't use numbers:

```
Input: ['car-strong', 'car', 'truck-weak']
Output: ['car-strong', 'truck-weak']
```

We might have 'truck', 'bananas', 'apple',  and things would be 'apple-10'.

Note that the "type" (car, truck, apple etc) is always the beginning of the word.

The typical list to parse is around 5-10 elements long.  (brute forceable i guess?)

But there are around 200,000 of these short lists to "clean"... is also the issue.

Comment: You forgot to share you attempt at solving this.

Comment: will these elements have always the same format? `something-number`? or are they arbitrary strings?

Comment: @torresmateo  updated to show that it can be string as well.

Comment: Why not just remove elements without a `'-'` in them? I know this is redementary but seems this could be a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

brute force

```
l =['car', 'car-10', 'truck-20']
remove_me = [x for x in l 
    if any([y.startswith(x) for y in l if x!=y])]
result = [x for x in l if x not in remove_me]
```

For better performance, order the list alphabetically to find candidate 'superset' faster, e.g. along the lines of

[Python: Remove elements from the list which are prefix of other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395540/python-remove-elements-from-the-list-which-are-prefix-of-other)

Comment: I think you're missing some brackets

Comment: And this only works if the substring is in the beginning. What happens when it's not at the start of the string?

Comment: In every of OPs examples it's at the beginning. They should supply a better example if so

Comment: use keyword `in` if need in the middle cases

Comment: string is always in beginning, updated question to reflect.

Comment: I would suggest `to_remove` be a `set` not a `list`.

Comment: that minor improvement does not change overal performance but less accesible to beginners

Comment: @serge why does listing it alphabetically make a difference?  it should still do exhaustive N^2 search i think.  see link now.

Comment: see the link for full solution and explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that should work for all kind input formats:

```
input = ['car-strong', 'car', 'truck-weak']
delete = []

for idx,str in enumerate(input):
    for idx2,str2 in enumerate(input):
        if str in str2 and idx != idx2:
            delete.append(str)

for str in delete:
    input.remove(str)

print(input)
```